# How to display the different options in new line in shell script using "read -p" option

Tags: linux, newline, centos7

I want that when i run the shell script as shown below. the options inside read

```
while true; do
  read -p $"1. Show disk usage.\n 2. Show system uptime.\n3. Show the user logged into the system. \nWhat do you want to do? (Enter q to quit.)" CHOICE
  case $CHOICE in
  1)
    df -h
    ;;

  2)
    uptime
    ;;

  3)
    who
    ;;

  q)
    echo "Goodbye!"
    break
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Invalid option entered"
    ;;
  esac

done

echo
```

I have used \n option but that does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use `$'..'` instead of `$".."`:

```
$ echo $"foo\nbar\nbaz"
foo\nbar\nbaz

$ echo $'foo\nbar\nbaz'
foo
bar
baz
```

`$".."` is a localized string while `$'..'` expands escape sequences.

Comment: I tried $'..' this option and it worked Thanks